# How to parameterize Kubeflow Pipelines environment variables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I am exploring Vertex AI Pipelines for running machine learning training jobs. The [kubeflow pipeline docs](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/component-development/) are clear about how to parameterize the commands/arguments of a container.

Is it also possible to pass a input to an environmental variable or image name of a component? This [swagger schema](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/86313242531a29b59c80d66b90bcd36e178318c2/sdk/python/kfp/components/structures/components.json_schema.json#L145) for a component suggests that this can be done, but this example fails:

```
implementation:
  container:
    image: {concat: ["us.gcr.io/vcm-ml/emulator", {inputValue: tag}]
    # command is a list of strings (command-line arguments). 
    # The YAML language has two syntaxes for lists and you can use either of them. 
    # Here we use the "flow syntax" - comma-separated strings inside square brackets.
    command: [
      python3, 
      # Path of the program inside the container
      /pipelines/component/src/program.py,
      --input1-path,
      {inputPath: input_1},
      --param1, 
      --output1-path, 
    ]
    env:
      NAME: {inputValue: env}
inputs:
- {name: tag, type: String}
- {name: env, type: String}
- {name: input_1, type: String, description: 'Data for input_1'}
```

Is passing an `{inputValue}` to `container.env` or `container.tag` supported. Alternatively, is it possible to add an environment variable or change the image name using the V2 python DSL.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion.

Unfortunately, the JsonSchema is wrong here (i.e. it differs from the [implementation](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/c89ed71cf6339cdcdd957d4dca4b1f32c10db9c9/sdk/python/kfp/components/_structures.py#L332)). Same with the `image`.

The env implementation uses static map. And `image` is static as well.

In Kubeflow Pipelines (v1) there is a chance you might be able to set environment varible to a dynamic value after you create component instance. But This probably won't work in Vertex Pipelines.

```py
my_task = my_op(...)
my_task.container.add_env_variable(V1EnvVar(name='MSG', value=task1.outputs["out1"]))
```

If this does not work you can create a GitHub issue in the KFP repo regarding the env support.

For image we usually advice to have separate component files for different images.

A workaround would be a small wrapper script that sets the variable:

```yaml
inputs:
- {name: tag, type: String}
- {name: env, type: String}
- {name: input_1, type: String, description: 'Data for input_1'}
implementation:
  container:
    image: "us.gcr.io/vcm-ml/emulator"
    command:
    - sh
    - -ec
    - 'NAME="$0" "$@"' # Set NAME to the first arg and execute the rest
    - {inputValue: env}
    - python3
      # Path of the program inside the container
    - /pipelines/component/src/program.py
    - --input1-path
    - {inputPath: input_1}
    - --param1 
    - --output1-path
```